# Connect simple one view app to mySQL database for login?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, database, xcode

I am trying to make a one view app with a login page first of all connected to a mysql database, what is the best way to do this? JSON?

First of all do I need to use Swift or?

I used Xcode in 2012 and it has change a lot since then...

Thanks!!

Comment: choice is urs, mysql database - is your server or local, if it is server use json, else if it is in local data base, use sqlite or coredata

Comment: thanks for the info!

Comment: welcome bro.....

Comment: this works well ,)